# List system fonts via Heroku CLI

Tags: fonts, heroku-cli

Our repo includes a .fonts folder. I understand that files contained in that folder of our repo get installed to the underlying system of our Heroku node.js app. Using the Heroku CLI how can I get a list of the installed font resources of our app?  I know that for Ubuntu the command is 'fc-list'. Is there something similar for the Heroku CLI?

Answer (score 0):

Very old question here, I was just looking to copy paste some cli code.

From my understanding there isn't much in there. You'll have to include a fonts folder in your build somewhere, which is what I do now.

But, if you'd really like to explore the your Heroku app, from terminal run:

```
heroku run bash
```

then fonts on linux systems are usually located in '/usr/share/fonts/' so

```
cd /usr/share/fonts/
```

from there there's an opentype folder and a truetype folder with a couple of default fonts (on Heroku-20): Dejavu (truetype) and urw-base35 (opentype)